# Attach a file with that mail function. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am using mailto function within anchor tag. I can write subject, cc bcc, body things with that. But I want to attach a file with that mail function. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

[PHPMailer github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

using this library you can add attachments using `mailto` .have a look..this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach files in the `mailto:` protocol, and it would be a gaping security hole if it were possible.

You can use php mail function to send mail with attachment.